# How to move accessibilty focus from UITableViewHeader to Cell in UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, accessibility

I have one `UITableView` where I am adding a header using `UITableHeaderView`. 
The header view is occupying fit to screen in small devices because of its content. And in accessibility it's not moving from table header view to table cell since those cell are not getting visible in screen.

**This is working fine in iOS8 but not in iOS9.**

I know accessibility post notification should work, but not sure where to fire the notification since there is no way to know that content reading done for table header view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question. I fixed the issue by using accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused. I checked for last label in header view whenever receives i scrolling table on tab so that other cell could get visible and voiceover can move to next element.